# Converting QGIS 2 plugin to QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis

A while ago I made a plugin for QGIS for myself.

This worked until version 2.18. Now I have version 3.0 and would like to use this plugin here too. But I get some error messages. I have been able to solve most of them fairly easily. Only I can not do this. Perhaps there is someone among you who can help me in this.

This is the code that I used before.

```
 def initGui(self):
    """Create menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ":/plugins/BFVWtools/"

    """Create the menu entrie Configuratie and toolbar icon inside the QGIS GUI."""
    self.add_action(icon_path + "/icon.png", text=self.tr(u'Configuratie'), 
    callback=self.run, parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.action = QAction( QIcon( os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/icon.png" ), "Configuratie", 
    self.iface.mainWindow() )
    QObject.connect(self.action, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.run)
```

The error message I get is the following

```
AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'connect' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 345, in startPlugin
plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "C:/Users/Automatisering/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\BFVWtools\bfvw_tools.py", line 212, in initGui
QObject.connect(self.action, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.run)
AttributeError: type object 'QObject' has no attribute 'connect'
```

Apparently there is no attribute 'Connect' in QObject

---

After your explanation, I have converted everything to PyQt5 and changed the connect to slot. The strange thing is that I now get all the entrys from the menu one after the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the old style of connect. There is this blogpost explaining the old/new style of connect, which was already recommended in Qt4: https://robertbasic.com/blog/connecting-signals-and-slots-with-pyqt-the-new-style/

Try this:

```
your_object.name_of_signal.connect(your_function_slot)
```

So your code would be like:

```
self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
```

Answer (score 4):

QObject does have the connect function - without seeing the rest of your script, it's tough to know for sure, but it looks like you need to set the import for PyQt5 as opposed to PyQt4, per [the update notes to the QGIS3.0 migration page](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/wiki/Plugin-migration-to-QGIS-3). This dependency change is in addition to the shift from Python 2 to 3, so both issues have to be considered.

Native Python 2.7 (which I use still) has a Tools\Scripts folder that includes a 2to3.py script that corrects version 2 to 3 migration issues.  According to the page linked above, you should have a similar script that includes updates to all QGIS script changes:  `path/to/QGIS/scripts/2to3`

Try the following import statements at the top of your plugin code, or simply change all your current imports to PyQt5 manually:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

Comment: To import PyQt whatever the version, you can do 'from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import X'. No need to update yoru code when QGIS will use Qt6 for instance.